# Plot function in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

I opened Octave today and this showed up on the Command window.

```
warning: function .\plot.m shadows a core library function
```

I tried running an .m file with plot functions but it doesn't work. I tried uninstalling and re-installing Octave but it's still there. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You saved one of your files as `plot.m`, and so Octave now does not know how to differentiate between yours, and the standard `plot()` function. It will always use yours. Octave is simply telling you that this is happening and that you should probably change your local file name to something else.